# django-tables2: Adding a new custom column not found in model

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have the following table:

```
class TaskTable(tables.Table):

    def render_foo(self):
        raise Exception()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['foo']
```

for the following model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    priority = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

According to the docs, `render_foo` won't be executed if it is considered an *empty value*.

My requirement is that `foo` is not found in the Model. How can I implement the column `foo`?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass an `empty_values=()` keyword argument to the column, to quote [the docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html):

> render methods are only called if the value for a cell is determined to be not an empty value. When a value is in`Column.empty_values`, a default value is rendered instead (both Column.render and `Table.render_FOO` are skipped).

In your case, the 'value' for your non-existing column is `None`, so if that value is in `empty_values`, the default value (`-` by default is rendered).

So in code, it could look like this:

```
class TaskTable(tables.Table):
    foo = tables.Column(empty_values=())

    def render_foo(self):
        raise Exception()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

[relevant docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html)