# Example of how to Subclass Column() in Django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

Can anyone point me to an example of how to subclass the base Column() in django-tables2 please.  By default the django-tables2 base Column() attrs supports 'th', 'td', 'cell' and 'a' as detailed in the [documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#booleancolumn), which also states that this can be

> extended by subclasses to allow arbitrary HTML attributes to be added
>   to the output.

What I want to try and do, which may be either ambitious or flat out stupid and wrong, is to add a 'ul' attribute (and subsequently 'li' attributes) so that I can render a dropdown menu in a cell. My thinking is to have an options button on each row of my table that provides the user with the various options of 'delete', 'copy', 'archive' etc via a css or js dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-tables2 ships with some custom columns, you can have a look at their implementation here:

https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/tree/master/django_tables2/columns

The [`JSONColumn`](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/columns/jsoncolumn.py) might be a good example:

```
class JSONColumn(BaseLinkColumn):
    def __init__(self, json_dumps_kwargs=None, **kwargs):
        self.json_dumps_kwargs = (
            json_dumps_kwargs if json_dumps_kwargs is not None else {"indent": 2}
        )

        super(JSONColumn, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def render(self, record, value):
        return format_html(
            "<pre {}>{}</pre>",
            AttributeDict(self.attrs.get("pre", {})).as_html(),
            json.dumps(value, **self.json_dumps_kwargs),
        )
```

The implementation adds one argument to the columns constructor which allows a the programmer to change the parameters passed to `json.dumps()`. In its `render()` method, it extracts attributes for the `<pre>`-tag from the `attrs`-dict. This enables the user to do

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    data = tables.JSONColumn(attrs={"pre": {"class": "json-data"}})
```

Which will be used to render the column like this:

```
<pre class="json-data">{
    "key": "value"
}</pre>
```

Also note that if your create a column which is not directly viewing data, [you might want to set `empty_values=()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483162/517560)

Comment: Thanks Jieter.  I was going around in circles as to where to start with this but I think I understand a bit more now, so I'll go and have a play and see how I get on.